# Есть ли смысл в использовании System.gc()?

Tags: java

В Java вроде как есть автоматический Garbage Collector, но каков тогда смыл в данном методе? Если вообще какой-то резон его вызывать, если точно знаешь, что тот или другой объект больше не будет использоваться в программе?

Comment: Смысл в том, что есть определенный круг программистов, которые не доверяют мусорщику джавы, принудительно отключет его и потом своими силами чистит мусор. Часто такое умопомешательство (ИМХО) случается с теми, кто скатился с более низкоуровнего ЯП (дельфи, си).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Смысла в его использовании практически никакого. Я только один раз увидел, реальное применение этого метода (на андроиде). В программе создавались большие массивы (несколько мегабайт) и по 10-15 штук в секунду. и после каждого использования стоял `gc()`. Как только его убираешь, приложение падало через несколько секунд. А так могло проработать с пол часика.

Но потом я просто понял, что двух массивов будет достаточно и не нужно удалять, а можно переиспользовать их. gc с кода ушел, обработка стала быстрее (что бы там java программисты не говорили, но выделение и освобождение памяти достаточно затратное, особенно, если запрашивать большие объемы), падать перестало совсем.

Вывод:

- Если с программы убрать gc() и она продолжает работать, тогда нужно его убрать. Значит уборщик и так справляется с задачей. А программист параноик.
- Если убирание gc() приводит к падению программы, нужно поискать, где же выделяется память под объекты, которую уборщик не успевает подчищать. Прикрутить к этом пул объектов. Даже если на первый взгляд кажется, что такой пул съест больше памяти, это не так (нужно проверять только профайлером, благое дело в java их хватает и они достаточно информативны).
- Если, даже будучи обложенной кучей gc(), все равно падает от недостатка памяти, значит нужно менять алгоритмы, структуру данных, тюнить GC (они есть разные), а как крайнюю меру - менять язык программирования. Возможно, не для всего кода, а просто пару нативных функций написать.

Comment: Но потом я просто понял, что двух массивов будет достаточно и не нужно удалять

Comment: вот он опыт :)

Comment: код, который я переделывал был  не мой. Его самые настоящие индусы писали.

Comment: > А программист параноик.

я не параноик и хватит меня преследовать !

Comment: оставайтесь на месте, за Вами выехали. Скоро будут.

Comment: > что бы там java программисты не говорили, но выделение и освобождение памяти достаточно затратное, особенно, если запрашивать большие объемы
Тут дело в тюнинге GC, нужно добиваться дешевого создания и удаления объектов (инкремент при аллокации и бесплатное удаление из эдена) или уходить в allocation free

Answer (score 4):

Этот метод нечего не гарантирует и может быть проигнорирован JVM. Обычно его не рекомендуют использовать, хотя и вреда особо от него нету.

Answer (score 4):

Смысл есть при совпадении 2-х условий:

1. Вы точно знаете, что JVM не будет "сильно занят"
2. Вы точно знаете, что есть "что освободить/почистить"

Обычно такая ситуация наблюдается при завершении проги или выходе из проги, когда вам надо почистить какие-нибудь ключи, сессии и проч. приватные вещи, которые вы не хотите чтобы оставались в памяти.

Comment: > почистить какие-нибудь ключи, сессии и проч. приватные вещи, которые вы не хотите чтобы оставались в памяти.

а разве gc вызывает заполнение памяти нулями? это что то новенькое. По факту завершения программы gc вызывать точно не нужно. Именно на этом фокусе java и выигрывает в синтетических тестах у плюсов - нет деструкторов - нет проблем (явных).

Comment: .. и для чистки сессия и буферов, есть другие методы, типа flush()

Comment: @KoVadim а что деструктор разве заполняет нулями?

Comment: Нет конечно. Но кто мешает добавить строку другую нужному классу в деструктор?

Comment: @KoVadim в Java есть отдаленная тень деструктора `finalize()`, которая может выполнить схожую функцию

Comment: что бы принудительно занулять память finalize() не подходит, потомучто его вызов не гарантирован, а если он и вызовется то неизвестно когда. лучше просто метод вызвать в нужное время.